# Wordpress media queries not working at all

Tags: css, media-queries

Wordpress does not seem to respect any of my media queries. For example, putting this at the bottom of my `style.css` does nothing:

```
@media only screen and max-width(700) {

    body {background-color: black !important;}
}
```

I'm using a custom theme, but it's fairly straightforward and all my other styles work fine. What am I missing? I don't think I'm doing the CSS wrong, so my thinking is that it's some conflict with Wordpress.

I have this in my `header.php`:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: This has _nothing_ to do with WordPress.

Comment: Also, it's good form to show your research.  You clearly gamed the title, as "Media Queries not working" and "Media Queries Not Working At All" are both duplicate titles, so you've added "WordPress" to make it pass.  So - did you look into any of those solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for the media query has to be like this (note the exact syntax):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) { ... }
```